# Javascript: Generating ECDSA public key from private key

Tags: javascript, frontend, ecdsa

Is there any library that supports deriving the ecdsa public key from the private key for javascript (frontend)?  (With the private key, we can generate the corresponding public key)

I studied the [localethereum white paper](https://whitepaper.localethereum.com/#sec-undefined.Cryptography-layer), and I would like to implement the crypto layer.

It says:

> AccountKeyIdentityPublic — Using the SECP‐256k1 curve, an ECDSA public key that corresponds to AccountKeyIdentityPrivate.

However, it seems that lots of libraries 
([1](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/issues/322),
[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API))  do not support this function.

Anyone can provide me some advise? Thanks!

Comment: I think it helps you https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign

Comment: @huynhsamha Thanks~ But it also cannot assign the private key. That is, the private key is generated randomly. [generateKeyPairHex()](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KJUR.crypto.ECDSA.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do such thing with a library that support point multiplication.
To get your public key, you just have to multiply a generation point G by your private key.

For example with **elliptic** package :

```
var EC = require('elliptic').ec;

// Create and initialize EC context
// (better do it once and reuse it)
var ec = new EC('secp256k1');

// Then generate the public point/key corresponding to your secret key.
var pubPoint = ec.keyFromSecret(secret).getPublic();
```

Comment: Yes, your method is right. But I afraid that if I code it by myself, there may exist some security issues....

Comment: I found a solution by using dist/elliptic.js in elliptic project.
Include it by <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/elliptic.js"></script>
And
var ec = new EC('secp256k1');
var pubPoint = ec.keyFromSecret(secret).getPublic();

Comment: i got elliptic from cdnjs, no `.keyFromSecret` method, only keyFromPublic and keyFromPrivate